# Maven Increment property which is number inside the pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-3

I want to change pom.xml property

So Build Number Maven Plugin not solve my problem because its based on other file (buidnumber.properties)

**Given** In pom.xml I have property *my.number*

```
<properties>
    <my.number>125</my.number>
</properties>
```

**When** I run some maven plugin goal

**Than** In pom.xml I have incremented *my.number* property by one:

```
<properties>
    <my.number>126</my.number>
</properties>
```

So what need to be done is to Increment value of property my.value by **1** each time I call maven goal. Is it possible to achieve that by some plugin?

Comment: Can you elaborate what the real reason for this is? What do you like to achieve with this?

Comment: During release process I want to increase this number for android project.
1. my.number is for     android:versionCode in Android Manifest.
2. When I perform release I want trigger increment version number by one
3. Release plugin commits only changed pom.xmls

Comment: what this number means? is it the version?

Comment: Number is Integer and need be increment on every release. Than on Google play. Store knows that is new version of application. Its android:versionCode in Android Manifest

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autoincrement version number in pom.xml and display it in the app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888219/autoincrement-version-number-in-pom-xml-and-display-it-in-the-app)

Comment: Why not making a version from your version control like git hash or svn revision?

Comment: Im using git repository. Git hash is string
android:versionCode need to be Number and new version always need to be greater than last one.

Comment: If you use release plugin with every release you will get a new incremented version number like from `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` you will get a release `1.0.0` and the next development version will be `1.0.1-SNAPSHOT` with the release you will get `1.0.1`etc. so what's the problem?

Comment: Version Name and version code is different Lets say (VersionName and VersionCode is a pair):
VersionName=1.0.0 VersionCode=1,
VersionName=1.0.1 VersionCode=2,
VersionName=1.1.0 VersionCode=3,
VersionName=2.0.0 VersionCode=4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Maven Versions plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-properties-mojo.html), or maybe in your case the [replacer plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/) is even better.

You run the replacer-plugin by command such as:
mvn replacer:replace -Dccih.origion="my.number" -Dccih.target="some new value"

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>replace</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <file>pom.xml</file>
          <replacements>
            <replacement>
              <token>${ccih.origion}</token>
              <value>${ccih.target}</value>
            </replacement>
          </replacements>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

so if you run your maven commands using a tool such as Jenkins or Hadson you can calculate the new value there, based on the existing one.

Comment: Maven versions plugin or replaces plugin will work. But need to know, what I need to check. I want to calculate new value. Which is ++my.number.  What I'm missing is how to get value increment by 1 and than populate to plugins which you proposed.

Answer (score 1):

This will change your pom.xml accordingly:

```
mvn versions:set-property -Dproperty=my.number -DnewVersion=126
```